# Users report occasional message: Message: 'JSON' is undefined

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I have a site which has been running for a year now and new users sign up every day. However, there has been a trickle of users reporting the following error: Message: 'JSON' is undefined. I always try to recreate their environment and find the issue, but can never recreate the issue. Thankfully, someone has provided the details of the error message now - is this something I can fix at my end or is it specific to the user's browser settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens in older browsers (such as IE7), which do not support native `JSON`. Include [`json2.js`](http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js) (CDN) in your webpage (from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: Thanks - is it possible then that some IE7 users won't experience this issue and others will, depending on the exact version they are using? It just seems to be a sporadic issue, with the majority of IE7 users unaffected

Comment: @bsod99 That is *not possible*. IE7 doesn't define the `JSON` object. See also http://caniuse.com/#search=json

Comment: Ok, very strange. Well, I take it I need to add json2.js before jquery, then I can go back to the user who reported this error and see if it's gone

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/healthvault/thread/68bf3397-b9ec-4d0a-b432-03a4afbcc13d